# Sodoku game and how to input numbers into my grid using Math.random()

Tags: java

I have made a sudoku game where the computer plays against the user(human) and need help implementing one part of it. I have tried everything!!
So I've done Mode 1 where the user selects moves for both the human and the computer using StdIn, but now I have to do mode 0 where the computer does a random move.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class Twoduko {

    static int Board[][];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StdOut.print("Enter the height of the grid:");
        int H = StdIn.readInt();
        StdOut.print("Enter the width of the grid:");
        int W = StdIn.readInt();
        StdOut.print("Enter the mode:");
        int M = StdIn.readInt();

        generateBoard(H, W);
        drawBoard(H, W);
        playGameModeZero(H, W, M);
        playGameModeOne(H, W, M);
        playGameModeTwo(H, W, M);
    }

    public static void generateBoard(int H, int W) {

        int tempBoard[][] = new int[H * H][W * W];

        for (int i = 0; i < H * H; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < W * W; j++) {

                tempBoard[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        Board = tempBoard;
    }

    public static void drawBoard(int H, int W) {
        if (W == 2) {
            System.out.println("+---+---++---+---+");
        } else if (W == 3) {
            System.out.println("+---+---+---++---+---+---++---+---+---+");
        } else if (W == 4) {
            System.out.println("+---+---+---+---++---+---+---+---++---+---+---+---++---+---+---+---+");
        } else if (W == 5) {
            System.out.println(
                    "+---+---+---+---+---++---+---+---+---+---++---+---+---+---+---++---+---+---+---+---++---+---+---+---+---+");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < H * H; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < W * W; j++) {

                if (W == 2 && j == 2) {
                    System.out.print("||");
                } else if (W == 3 && j == 3) {
                    System.out.print("||");
                } else if (W == 3 && j == 6) {
                    System.out.print("||");
                } else if (W == 4 && j == 4) {
                    System.out.print("||");
                } else if (W == 4 && j == 8) {
                    System.out.print("||");
                } else if (W == 4 && j == 12) {
                    System.out.print("||");
                } else if (W == 5 && j == 5) {
                    System.out.print("||");
                } else if (W == 5 && j == 10) {
                    System.out.print("||");
                } else if (W == 5 && j == 15) {
                    System.out.print("||");
                } else if (W == 5 && j == 20) {
                    System.out.print("||");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("|");
                }
                System.out.print(Board[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("" + "|");
            System.out.println("");

            if (W == 2 && H == 2) {
                if (i == 1) {
                    System.out.println("+===+===++===+===+");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("+---+---++---+---+");
                }
            }
            if (W == 3 && H == 3) {
                if (i == 2) {
                    System.out.println("+===+===+===++===+===+===++=== +===+===+");
                } else if (i == 5) {
                    System.out.println("+===+===+===++===+===+===++=== +===+===+");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("+---+---+---++---+---+---++---+---+---+");
                }
            }
            if (W == 3 && H == 2) {
                if (i == 1) {
                    System.out.println("+===+===+===++===+===+===++=== +===+===+");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("+---+---+---++---+---+---++---+---+---+");
                }
            }
            if (W == 4 && H == 4) {
                if (i == 3) {
                    System.out.println("+===+===+===+===++===+===+===+ ===++===+===+===+===++===+===+===+===+");
                } else if (i == 7) {
                    System.out.println("+===+===+===+===++===+===+===+ ===++===+===+===+===++===+===+===+===+");
                } else if (i == 11) {
                    System.out.println("+===+===+===+===++===+===+===+ ===++===+===+===+===++===+===+===+===+");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("+---+---+---+---++---+---+---+---++---+---+---+---++---+---+---+---+");
                }
            }
            if (W == 4 && H == 2) {
                if (i == 1) {
                    System.out.println("+===+===+===+===++===+===+===+ ===++===+===+===+===++===+===+===+===+");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("+---+---+---+---++---+---+---+---++---+---+---+---++---+---+---+---+");
                }
            }
            if (W == 4 && H == 3) {
                if (i == 2) {
                    System.out.println("+===+===+===+===++===+===+===+ ===++===+===+===+===++===+===+===+===+");
                } else if (i == 5) {
                    System.out.println("+===+===+===+===++===+===+===+ ===++===+===+===+===++===+===+===+===+");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("+---+---+---+---++---+---+---+---++---+---+---+---++---+---+---+---+");
                }
            }
            if (W == 5 && H == 2) {
                if (i == 1) {
                    System.out.println(
                            "+===+===+===+===+===++===+===+===+===+===++===+== =+===+===+===++===+===+===+===+===++===+===+===+== =+===+");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(
                            "+---+---+---+---+---++---+---+---+---+---++---+---+---+---+---++---+---+---+---+---++---+---+---+---+---+");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void playGameModeZero(int H, int W, int M) {
        if (M == 0) {
            boolean play = true;
            boolean humanTurn = false;
            boolean computerTurn = false;
            int turn = 0;
            if (turn % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Computer's turn");
            }
            if (turn % 2 == 0) {
                computerTurn = true && humanTurn == false;
            }
            if (turn % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.println("Human's turn");
            }
            if (turn % 2 != 0) {
                humanTurn = true && computerTurn == false;
            }
            turn++;
            while (play) {

                if (humanTurn) {
                    int row = 0;
                    int column = 0;
                    int entry = 0;
                    StdOut.print("Enter row:");
                    row = StdIn.readInt();
                    StdOut.print("Enter column:");
                    column = StdIn.readInt();
                    StdOut.print("Enter your entry value:");
                    entry = StdIn.readInt();

                    if (entry <= 0 || entry >= (W * W + 1)) {
                        play = false;
                        System.out.println("Illegal move.");
                    }

                    if (row > W * W || column > H * H) {
                        play = false;
                        System.out.println("Illegal move. ");
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < H * H - 1; i++) {
                        if (Board[i][column] == entry) { // check row
                            play = false;
                            System.out.println("Illegal move.");
                        }
                    }

                    for (int j = 0; j < W * W; j++) { // check column
                        if (Board[row][j] == entry) {
                            play = false;
                            System.out.println("Illegal move.");
                        }
                    }
                    int subRow = 0;
                    int subCol = 0;
                    subRow = row / H;
                    subCol = column / W;

                    for (int i = 0; i < H; i++) { // check subgrid
                        for (int j = 0; j < W; j++) {
                            if (Board[i + H * subRow][j + W * subCol] == entry) {
                                play = false;
                                System.out.println("Illegal move.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (computerTurn) {
                    Board[(int) Math.random() * (W * W)][(int) Math.random() * (H * H)] = (int) (Math.random() * H * W)
                            + 1;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void playGameModeOne(int W, int H, int M) {
        if (M == 1) {
            boolean play = true;
            boolean humanTurn = false;
            boolean computerTurn = false;
            int turn = 0;
            if (turn % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Computer's turn");
            }
            if (turn % 2 == 0) {
                computerTurn = true && humanTurn == false;
            }
            if (turn % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.println("Human's turn");
            }
            if (turn % 2 != 0) {
                humanTurn = true && computerTurn == false;
            }
            turn++;

            while (play) {
                int row = 0;
                int column = 0;
                int entry = 0;
                StdOut.print("Enter row:");
                row = StdIn.readInt();
                StdOut.print("Enter column:");
                column = StdIn.readInt();
                StdOut.print("Enter your entry value:");
                entry = StdIn.readInt();

                if (entry <= 0 || entry >= (W * W + 1)) {
                    play = false;
                    System.out.println("Illegal move.");
                }

                if (row > W * W || column > H * H) {
                    play = false;
                    System.out.println("Illegal move. ");
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < H * H - 1; i++) {
                    if (Board[i][column] == entry) { // check row
                        play = false;
                        System.out.println("Illegal move.");
                    }
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < W * W; j++) { // check column
                    if (Board[row][j] == entry) {
                        play = false;
                        System.out.println("Illegal move.");
                    }
                }
                int subRow = 0;
                int subCol = 0;
                subRow = row / H;
                subCol = column / W;

                for (int i = 0; i < H; i++) { // check subgrid
                    for (int j = 0; j < W; j++) {
                        if (Board[i + H * subRow][j + W * subCol] == entry) {
                            play = false;
                            System.out.println("Illegal move.");
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (play == true && turn % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Computer's turn");
                }
                if (play == true && turn % 2 != 0) {
                    System.out.println("Human's turn");
                }
                turn++;

                Board[row][column] = entry;
                if (play) {
                    drawBoard(W, H);

                }
            }
            if (computerTurn && play == false) {

                {
                    System.out.println("Human wins!");
                }
                if (humanTurn && play == false) {

                    System.out.println("Computer wins!");
                }
            }
        }    
}
```

So as you can see for Mode 0, I started by making an integer to alternate between the human and computers turns and if its the computer's turn the boolean computerTurn is true and vice versa. Except whatever I've tried, a random integer won't input in the grid I've drawn.

```
if (computerTurn) {
    Board[(int) Math.random() * (W * W)][(int) Math.random() * (H * H)] = (int) (Math.random() * H * W)
    + 1;
    }
```

So that is the part of the code which "should" input a random number (ie. if the grid is 2x2, then it'll be a random number from 1-4 and if its 3x3, it'll be a random number from 1-9. But whenever I run the code, it doesn't place a random number in my grid.

Comment: That a lot of code (too much for me to read) but the only difference between user input and computer input should be the source of the value (Scanner vs Random), the rest of should use the exact same code (the same method to be exact). If this doesn't answer your problem, please post an indented [mcve]

Comment: Full stop. Right here right now. A) that preview function on the edit window exists for a reason. Same for all the rules on markup. You do not dump 100+ lines of code that is **not at all** indented. That makes it close to impossible to read that source code; and at least me: makes stop wanting to help you immediately. B) you are killing yourself. Before doing anything else, you should step back and identify *abstractions* that help you simplify your code. Such endless nested ifs and loops - that is "IMPOSSIBLE to maintain" code. Sorry, but your problem is not "function" but **form** ...

Comment: I don't see how using a random number could work, what if the first call gives you a 1 and the next call 1 again?

Comment: @GhostCat I fully agree, and it makes me wonder if there's something SO-like that lets more experienced developers coach new people. I remember starting off in my CS studies with only experience in BASIC and having no idea what all this object-oriented stuff was about. Unfortunately most teachers only tell you "how" but not "why", so it takes a while before students understand that programs should not consist of global static variables being manipulated through objects. We scoff here at what we consider "bad" questions but the issue is often no-one teaches beginners right.

Comment: @G_H The problem is that there are **too** many newbies; and not enough "experts". The **correct** way of asking for such kind of things: putting up a very specific question, like "I am doing exactly xyz here; but I think that has abc downsides; what can i do about that" - that could give a good question here. If you have working code (that comes with a certain quality), codereview.stackexchange.com is an alternative, too.

Comment: @G_H But I get your point. But thing is: we can't solve all the problems in the world. I see my mission here to A) help as much as I can B) collect as much rep as I can C) improve quality on all ends as much as I can. But there are limits to what I can do ;-)

Comment: Hi Nicole. Once you get some code working, either via help here or from your own efforts, please do not try to overwrite the question with "solved" messages. In general, if you have acquired no answers _and_ you do not believe the question is of use to anyone in the future, you can try to delete the question. However, it looks like you received two answers below, so please reply to them and/or to vote/accept their efforts.

Answer (score 2):

In the code of `computerTurn`,

```
(int) Math.random() * (W * W)
```

This line will always give result as `0`.

[Math.random()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()) returns a double which varies from `0.0 <= Math.random() < 1.0` and when you do typecasting in `int` by from `double` by `(int) Math.random()` , It becomes `0`.

Then whatever you do with it, It remains still `0`.

So If you want to generate a random from `0` to `W*W` there, replace it with,

```
(int) (Math.random() * W * W)
```

Answer (score 1):

These lines are wrong:

```
if (turn % 2 == 0) {
     computerTurn = true && humanTurn == false;
}

if (turn % 2 != 0) {
    humanTurn = true && computerTurn == false;
 }
```

Here's what you meant to write:

```
if (turn % 2 == 0) {
    computerTurn = true;
    humanTurn = false;
}

if (turn %2 != 0) {
    computerTurn = false;
    humanTurn = true;
}
```

Comment: I expect those variables assignments could be set without the `if()` statements as well - essentially `computerTurn = (turn % 2 == 0)`, and then `humanTurn = !computerTurn`.